# How to use where clause after join tabel?

Tags: mysql

I have two table:

```
// refueling_data 
+----------+---------+
| distanse | user_id | 
+----------+---------+
|  61000   |    1    |
|  60000   |    1    | 
|  60000   |    3    |
+----------+---------+

// user
+----------+-----------+
| user_id  | username  |
+----------+-----------+
|    1     |   admin   |
|    3     |   user1   |
+----------+-----------+
```

Both tabale have more columns by to this principal is not necessary to show other data. Also when i try to put in WHERE clause column existing in table refueling_data everything is going correct. But is not working if i use column existing only in user tabel.

And here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT distance, username FROM refueling_data LEFT JOIN user ON refueling_data.user_id=user.user_id) AS tab WHERE tab.username =admin;
```

After execute query i get error:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'admin' in 'where clause'

The table i want to achieve:

```
// tab
+-----------+-----------+
| username  | distance  |
+-----------+-----------+
|  admin    |   60000   |
|  admin    |   61000   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Please give me advice on what mistake I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a subquery and since admin is a string you need to surround it with single quotes, `'admin'`

```
SELECT username, distance
FROM refueling_data r
JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.username = 'admin'
ORDER BY distance ASC -- if you want to sort on distance
```

Comment: Thank you Joakim Danielson, its correct. I forgot to put admin i quotation mark...